# Displaying unique transactions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, transactions

Currently there are multiple transactions with the same txnid. But for each transaction the payment mode is credit card, debit card or net banking.

If the customer has to pay $3000 he might pay that $3000 like $1000 with Credit card, $1000 with Debit Card, $1000 with Net banking.
Currently am displaying all those 3 transactions in 3 rows but with the same txnid. But I want to display those 3 transactions in a single row by mentioning in the payment mode column ($1000- Credit Card, $1000 Debit Card, $1000 Net bank)

Thanks for your help .

transactions.html.erb

```
  <tr>
          <th>Merchant Name</th>
          <th>Transaction ID</th>
          <th>Payment Mode</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Transaction Fee</th>
          <th>Discount</th>
          <th>Additional Charges</th>
          <th>Added On</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="details">
       <% @all_settlement_details.map(&:txnid).uniq.each do |sd|  %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= sd.merchantname %></td>
              <td><%= sd.txnid %></td>
              <td><%= get_mode_ui.value(sd.mode) %></td>
              <td><%= sd.amount %></td>
              <td><%= get_status(sd.status) %></td>
              <td><%= sd.mer_service_fee %></td>
              <td><%= sd.discount %></td>
              <td><%= sd.additional_charges%></td>
              <td><%= get_added_on_date sd.addedon %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
```

trasactions.helper.rb

```
  INDEX_OPTIONS = {'dashboard' => 'get_dashboard_data', 'merchants' => 'get_merchants', 'transactions' => 'get_transactions',
                   'admin' => 'get_admin_data', 'profile' => 'get_merchant_data'}

  INDEX_PARTIAL = {'dashboard' => 'dashboard', 'merchants' => 'merchant_list', 'transactions' => 'transactions',
                   'admin' => 'admin', 'profile' => 'merchant_profile'}

  AJAX_OPTIONS = {'stat-board' => 'get_stats', 'transactions' => 'get_graph_transactions', 'payment-methods' => 'get_payment_method_graph_data',
                  'merchants' => 'get_merchant_graph_data', 'merchant_profile' => 'get_merchant_profile_data', 'load_more' => 'load_more',
                  'merchant_list' => 'get_merchants'}

  AJAX_PARTIAL = {'stat-board' => 'stat_board', 'transactions' => 'transactions_graph', 'payment-methods' => 'payment_methods_graph',
                  'merchants' => 'merchant_graphs', 'load_more' => 'transaction_details', 'merchant_profile' => 'merchant_profile_detail',
                  'merchant_list' => 'filtered_merchants',}

  STATUS={"dropped"=>0,"bounced"=>1,"captured"=>2,"auth"=>3,"failed"=>4,"usercancelled"=>5,"pending"=>6}
  MODE={'CC'=>0,'DC'=>1,'NB'=>2,'EMI'=>3,'CASH'=>4,'IVR'=>5,'COD'=>6}
  MODE_UI = {'CC'=>'Credit Card','DC'=>'Debit Card','NB'=>'Net Banking','EMI'=>'EMI','CASH'=>'Cash','IVR'=>'IVR','COD'=>'Cash on Delivery'}
  PG_MODE = {'Credit Card'=>0,'Debit Card'=>1,'Net Banking'=>2,'EMI'=>3,'Cash'=>4,'IVR'=>5,'Cash on Delivery'=>6,'Others'=>nil}
  STATUS_UI={"Dropped"=>0,"Bounced"=>1,"Captured"=>2,"Authenticated"=>3,"Failed"=>4,"User Cancelled"=>5,"Pending"=>6}
  CARDTYPE={'domestic'=>1,'international'=>2}
  TRANSACTIONS = ["Merchant Name", "Transaction ID", "Payment Mode","Amount","Status","Transaction Fee","Discount","Additional Charges","Added On"]

  TXN_SUCCESS_STATUS = [2,3]
  TXN_FAILURE_STATUS = [0,1,4,5]
  TXN_PENDING_STATUS = 6

  PARTNER_PANEL_REDMINE_STATUS_MAPPING = {
      16  => "In Process",
      3  => "In Process",
      69  => "In Process",
      11  => "Line of Business Rejected",
      14  => "Live",
      42  => "In Process",
      51  => "In Process",
      15  => "In Process",
      17  => "In Process",
      64  => "In Process",
      46  => "In Process",
      62  => "Line of Business Rejected",
      65  => "In Process",
      18  => "Assigned to Sales",
      79  => "In Process",
      61  => "In Process",
      5  => "In Process",
      70  => "In Process",
      71  => "In Process",
      50  => "Line of Business Rejected",
      32  => "Contacted",
      48  => "In Process",
      59  => "In Process",
      49  => "In Process",
      47  => "In Process",
      60  => "In Process",
      29  => "Line of Business Rejected",
      78  => "Assigned to Sales"
  }

  PARTNER_PANEL_REDMINE_STATUS_MAPPING_UI = {
      "In Process" => "16,3,69,42,51,15,17,64,46,65,79,61,5,70,71,48,59,49,47,60",
      "Line of Business Rejected" => "11,62,50,29",
      "Assigned to Sales" => "78,18",
      "Live" => "14",
      "Contacted" => "32"
  }

  def get_status _status_flag
    STATUS.key(_status_flag)
  end

  def get_mode _mode_flag
    MODE.key(_mode_flag)
  end

  def get_mode_ui
    PG_MODE
  end

  def get_transactions_ui
    TRANSACTIONS
  end

  def get_status_ui
    STATUS_UI
  end

  def get_merchant_status_ui
    PARTNER_PANEL_REDMINE_STATUS_MAPPING_UI
  end

  def status_merchant
    PARTNER_PANEL_REDMINE_STATUS_MAPPING
  end

  def get_added_on_date _date
    _date.strftime("%A, %d %B\'%y %H:%M")
  end

  def link_to_add_issues(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_issues(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end

  def link_to_remove_issues(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_issues(this)")
  end

  def get_issue_object _partner
    _partner.issues.blank? ? _partner.class.reflect_on_association(:issues).klass.new : _partner.issues
  end

  def get_contact_detail_object issue
    issue.contact_detail.blank? ? issue.class.reflect_on_association(:contact_detail).klass.new : issue.contact_detail
  end

  def issue_contact_detail issue, contact_column_name
    issue.contact_detail ? issue.contact_detail.send(contact_column_name) : ""
  end

  def options_for_state(issue)
    options_for_select(Setting[:states].split(/\r\n/).sort, issue.state).html_safe
  end

  # First Landing page for a Partner
  def get_dashboard_data
    get_stats
    get_merchants
  end

  # Merchant list for a Partner
  def get_merchants
    _merchant_filter_scope = {'merchant_status' => ["merchant_status", (params[:merchant_status].split(',') rescue nil)],
                              'merchant_email' => ["merchant_mail", params[:merchant_email]],
                              'merchant_url' => ["merchant_url", params[:merchant_url]],
                              'merchant_mid' => ['payu_mid', params[:merchant_mid]],
                              'merchant_name' => ['merchant_name', params[:merchant_name]],
                              'order' => ['order_issue', params[:order]]
    }
    method_array = [['issues'],["page", params[:page]],["per", per_page_option],["date_filter", @start_date, @end_date]]
    @partner_merchants = call_scope_methods_dynamically(method_array, _merchant_filter_scope)
  end

  # Transactions for a Partner
  def get_transactions
    #get more records to load
    load_more
  end

  # Merchant Profile page for a Partner
  def get_merchant_data
    get_stats
    load_more
  end

  # Admin page for Partners
  def get_admin_data
    @partners = Partner.where(partner_admin: false)
  end

  # Stat Board tab on Dashboard
  def get_stats
    method_array = [['settlement_details'],['stat_board_details'],['count_as_graph_data']]
    method_array << ['merchant_mid', @merchant_mid] if @merchant_mid
    method_array = add_date_or_hour_filter method_array
    data1 = call_methods(method_array)
    method_array << ['group_by_settlements_date']
    data2 = call_methods(method_array)
    @graph_data = [data1, data2]
  end

  # Merchant tab on Dashboard
  def get_merchant_graph_data
    method_array = [['issues']]
    method_array = add_date_or_hour_filter method_array
    method_array << ['group_by_merchant_date']
    data1 = @bank_partner.issues.date_filter(@start_date, @end_date).group_by(&:status_id)
    data2 = call_methods(method_array)
    @merchant_status_hash = {}
    data1.each{|key, value| get_partner_status_hash(get_merchant_status(key), value.count)}
    [@merchant_status_hash, data2]
  end

  def get_merchant_status redmine_status
    PARTNER_PANEL_REDMINE_STATUS_MAPPING[redmine_status] || 'In Process'
  end

  def get_partner_status_hash key, value
    @merchant_status_hash.update({key => value}){|k, ov, nv| ov + nv}
  end

  # Transaction tab on Dashboard
  def get_graph_transactions
    method_array = [['settlement_details'],['count_as_graph_data']]
    method_array << ['merchant_mid', @merchant_mid] if @merchant_mid
    method_array = add_date_or_hour_filter method_array
    method_array << ['group_by_settlements_date']
    @data1 = call_methods(method_array << ["status", TXN_SUCCESS_STATUS])
    @data2 = call_methods(method_array << ["status", TXN_FAILURE_STATUS])
    @data3 = call_methods(method_array << ["status", TXN_PENDING_STATUS])
    [@data1, @data2, @data3]
  end

  # Payment Method tab on Dashboard
  def get_payment_method_graph_data
    method_array = [['settlement_details'],["date_filter", @start_date, @end_date],['payment_mode']]
    method_array << ['merchant_mid', @merchant_mid] if @merchant_mid
    method_array << ['count']
    call_methods(method_array)
  end

  def get_transaction_graph_hash successful, failure, pending
    data_array= []
    successful_hash = {}
    failure_hash = {}
    pending_hash = {}
    successful.each{|d| successful_hash.merge!({(d.hour rescue d.date) => d.graph_data})}
    failure.each{|d| failure_hash.merge!({(d.hour rescue d.date) => d.graph_data})}
    pending.each{|d| pending_hash.merge!({(d.hour rescue d.date) => d.graph_data})}
    (successful_hash.keys + failure_hash.keys + pending_hash.keys).uniq.each do |datetime|
      data_array << {'datetime'=> "#{datetime}",'successful'=> (successful_hash[datetime] || 0) ,'unsuccessful'=> (failure_hash[datetime] || 0) ,'pending'=> (pending_hash[datetime] || 0)}
    end
    data_array
  end

  private

  def load_more
    @all_settlement_details = get_all_settlement_details || []
  end

  def get_all_settlement_details
    # Offset increments by 10 and Limit remains 11
    _txn_filter_scope = {'transaction_status' => ["status", (params[:transaction_status].split(',') rescue nil)],
                         'payment_options' => ["payment_options", (params[:payment_options].split(',') rescue nil)],
                         'transaction_id' => ['transaction_id', params[:transaction_id]],
                         'transaction_amount' => ['amount_range', ((params[:transaction_amount].split(',')[0] || 0) rescue nil), ((params[:transaction_amount].split(',')[1] || 100000000) rescue nil)],
                         'merchant_mid' => ['merchant_mid',params[:merchant_mid]],
                         'merchant_name' => ['merchant_name', params[:merchant_name]],
                         'clicks' => ['txn_offset', ((params[:clicks].to_i)*10 rescue 0)]
    }
    method_array = [['settlement_details'],["date_filter", @start_date, @end_date]]
    method_array << ["txn_limit", 11] unless @csv_format
    method_array << ['merchant_mid', @merchant_mid] if @merchant_mid
    records = call_scope_methods_dynamically(method_array, _txn_filter_scope)
    records.empty? ? nil : records
  end
  # extend Object to introduce the call_methods method
  def call_methods(methods)
    methods.inject(@bank_partner) do |obj, method|
      case method.count
        when 3
          obj.send(method.first, method[1], method[2])
        when 2
          obj.send(method.first, method.last)
        when 1
          obj.send(method.first)
        else
          obj
      end
    end
  end

  def call_scope_methods_dynamically(_method_array, _method_hash)
    method_array = _method_array
    _dynamic_method_hash = _method_hash
    # Add scopes in the methods array to call dynamically
    params.each{|key, value| method_array << _dynamic_method_hash[key]}
    call_methods(method_array.compact)
  end

  def add_date_or_hour_filter _method_array
    if @start_date == @end_date
      @end_date = (Date.parse(@end_date) + 1.day).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
      _method_array << ['hour_filter']
    end
    _method_array << ["date_filter", @start_date, @end_date]
    _method_array
  end
```

My final output should be look like.

```
            Txnid                 payment mode            Amount
            23234XS24XS           $1000Credit Card,        $3000
                                  $1000 Debit Card,
                                  $1000 Net bank
```

Some one said I need to create a helper method for that. But I am not sure how!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `I want to display those 3 transactions in a single row by mentioning in the payment mode column`, are we talking db column or html table column ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what all those files you posted are for.  You say that you want the following in the db:

```
"$1000- Credit Card, $1000 Debit Card, $1000 Net bank"
```

First, you would never write that format to the db.  Instead, you would try to use a consistent format, like:

```
Credit Card:1000,Debit Card:1000,Net Bank:1000
```

Then you can retrieve that column and store it in a variable:

```
payment_mode = "Credit Card: 1000, Debit Card: 1000, Net Bank: 1000"
```

Then you can do:

```
payments = Hash[
  payment_mode
  .split(',')
  .map{|mode| mode.split(':')}
]

p payments

total = payment_by.values.sum
#total = payments.values.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)

taxnid = 123
first_line = true

puts "Taxnid\tPayment mode\t\tTotal" 

payments.each_pair do |type, amount|
  if first_line
    puts "#{taxnid}\t#{type} #{amount}\t#{total}"
    first_line = false
  else
    puts "\t#{type} #{amount}"
  end
end

--output:--
Taxnid  Payment mode        Total
123     Credit Card 1000    3000
        Debit Card 1000
        Net Bank 1000
```

If you actually want to create some html that displays that format, then substitute `<td>'s` and `<tr>'s`in the appropriate places: